# C++ - Memory Leak - Pointers to Struct

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, struct

I have a struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct Edge {
  ...
  struct Edge *next;      // linked list
} Edge;
```

I use it in many functions. For example, `print` receives a pointer to a struct (`root`). In the function, I need initialize a new pointer to `root` (and use it in a while loop to traverse a linked list). I don't understand how memory leaks work in C++.

If I do the following :

```
Edge *e = root;
```

And then use `e` in a while loop :

```
while (e != NULL) {
   // do stuff
   e = e->next;
}
```

Do I have to free the pointer `e`?  Since it points to a a struct I want to keep, I don't delete it? Or maybe should I use it that way?

```
void print(Edge* root)
  ...
  Edge *e = new Edge;
  e = root;
  ...

  /* Free e */
  delete e;
```

Comment: @user1436187 this comment is non-sense. He is using a linked list here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting confused between what a pointer is and its relation to allocating/freeing memory.  You can have any number of pointers pointing at a chunk of memory, but the memory should only be freed once.

Here, you're passing an `Edge*` into `print` to know where to start printing.  The local `Edge*` you declare doesn't need to have heap memory allocated to it, since `e` is just going to be used to point to the different elements of the linked list, not tracking the lifetime of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need new or delete, you are using a pointer to *index* a linked-list.

```
Edge *e = root;
```

This create a pointer to the node pointed by root, both e and root points to the same object.

```
while (e != NULL) {
   // do stuff
   e = e->next;
}
```

This is perfectly fine to iterate over a linked list.

By the way this is OK for educational purpose, in production code I would rather advise to use the STL and std::list.

Comment: there are lots of places where it's better to use your own structures instead of the standard.  especially one so easy to understand as a linked list.  also since it's not hard to keep interoperability with STL operations.

Comment: @Javier why spend time and energy reinventing the wheel? Especially when it's a free steel-belted radial with built-in deceleration technology and real-time viscosity-response sensors and *you have paces to go*? Oh, I think you just got me! fair play :))

Answer (score 0):

When you no longer need an object that you've created with `new`, you *must* end it's life-cycle with `delete`.

Comment: since that no object was created while traversing the list, there's nothing to release.